# How to execute a loop in matlab from C#?

Tags: c#, matlab, image-processing

This is my code in C#. I am trying to execute the for loop in matlab. I am able to send and receive images to and from matlab.

```
matlab.Execute("img_bw = im2bw(img_resize)");
matlab.Execute("input = imclose(img_bw, strel('disk', space));");
matlab.Execute("[labels, num] = bwlabel(input, 8);");
matlab.Execute("output = logical(zeros(size(input)));");

matlab.Execute("for i = 1:num ");
matlab.Execute("    [r, c] = find(labels==i)");
matlab.Execute("    x = round(mean(c))");
matlab.Execute("    y = round(mean(r))");
matlab.Execute("    output(y,x) = 1; ");
matlab.Execute("end;");
```

Now, if you look at the statement after ' matlab.Execute("output = logical(zeros(size(input)));"); ' ,  There is a for loop.

How do i execute that for loop successfully in matlab ? I am using matalb server to execute matlab commands on matalb. That is, I have a matlab installation on my pc.

Comment: Can't you pass the entire loop as a single command? Use a `StringBuilder` to build the entire string, then send it once through the `Execute()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you would have to pass everything as one string, with each line separated by a semicolon. Something like this

```
matlab.Execute("for i = 1:num; [r, c] = find(labels==i); x = round(mean(c));y = round(mean(r)); output(y,x) = 1; end;");
```

As Jensen mentioned in his comment, you could also just concatenate the code lines into one string and then pass that into the `matlab.Execute(codeString)` command.